# Angular input file click on Choose file stops working after some use on Brave and Chrome

Tags: angular, file, file-upload

I have a simple input file element:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input"
       (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>
```

After some use, it stops working, and the only way to make it work again is by closing the browser, not just the tab, but all of them, the entire browser, quit it and open it again. This is very annoying and I have no clue what's going on. Is there any cached thing that could be reset after every click without wiping the vale of the element that may make it work? Is this a known issue? What is it?

Apple M1 Pro, MacOS Monterey 12.3.1
Chrome: Version 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (arm64)
Brave: Version 1.38.115 Chromium: 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Can you post what `onFileSelected` do?

Answer (score 0):

in my case all tabs in chrome were closing after clicking

i solved like this,

<input #ınput hidden type="file" accept="file/* ,,text/* ,.pdf ,.csv" (change)="loadFileFromDevice($event)">

correct spelling --> accept="file/* ,,text/* ,.pdf ,.csv"

my misspell on here -->
accept="file/* ***,.text/**** ,.pdf ,.csv"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).